# @wire returning undefined for data and error

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

```
import {api, LightningElement, track, wire} from 'lwc';
import fetchAllAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/ContinuationCallAuraLWC.fetchAllAccounts';


const columns = [
    {label: 'AccountName', fieldName: 'Name', sortable: true},
    {label: 'Billing Address', fieldName: 'BillingCity', type: 'text', sortable: true},
    {label: 'Shipping Address', fieldName: 'ShippingCity', type: 'text', sortable: true},
    {label: 'Company Ext', fieldName: 'CompanyExtId__c', type: 'text', sortable: true},
    {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone', sortable: true},
];


export default class AccountPageAura extends LightningElement {
    @api isLoaded = false;
    @track data = [];
    @track columns = columns;
    @track accountsLoaded = false;

    @wire(fetchAllAccounts)
    wiredAccounts({data, error}) {
        if(data){
            this.accountsLoaded = true;
            this.data = data;
        }
    };

    connectedCallback() {
        this.isLoaded = !this.isLoaded;
    }

}
```

Html:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={accountsLoaded}>
    <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={data}
            columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
    </template>
    <div if:true={isLoaded}> <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading..."></lightning-spinner></div>
</template>
```

The table data never loads, but the same works when I use `imperatively`.

```
    connectedCallback() {
        this.isLoaded = !this.isLoaded;
        fetchAllAccounts().then(result => {
            this.data = result;
            this.isLoaded = !this.isLoaded;
        }).catch(error => {
            this.isLoaded = !this.isLoaded;
        });
    }
```

But the issue here is, when we call it like an async method, the UI thread gets stuck for few seconds to load data. Users cannot do anything. So I just wanted to check how does `@wire` behave.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you made `fetchAllAccounts` as cacheable=true ? else wire wont work

Comment: Yes, this was the issue, Thanks.